# How to join table with both equal and Not equal on same column

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables as below

TableA:

```
id   Country
----------
1     US
----------
2     SG
----------
3     EU
----------
4     IN
```

TableB:

```
Report   country
----------------
No       NOT US
---------------
Yes      US
```

Required output as below:

```
TableA.id   TableA.Country  TableB.country TableB.Report
--------------------------------------------------------
1            US                  US           Yes
--------------------------------------------------------
2            SG                NOT US          NO
-------------------------------------------------------
3            EU                NOT US          NO
---------------------------------------------------------
4            IN                NOT US          NO
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

use left join

```
select id,a.Country,coalesce(b.country,'NOT US') as Bcountry,
       coalesce(Report,'NO') as report
from tableA a left join tableB b on a.country=b.country
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have complex `join` conditions:

```
select a.*, b.*
from a join
     b
     on (a.country = 'US' and b.country = 'US') or
        (a.country <> 'US' and b.country = 'NOT US') ;
```

`or` in a query is usually a performance killer.  Often, this type of query is used to match a default value.  In such a case, one technique is two `left join`s:

```
select a.*,
       coalesce(b.country, bdef.country) as b_country,
       coalesce(b.report, bdef.report) as b_report
from a join
     b
     on a.country = b.country left join
     b bdef
     on b.country is null and
        bdef.country = 'NOT US'
```